# Qual a forma correta, "Franquiado" ou "Franqueado"

Tags: significado, ortografia, diferenças

Vejo sempre essas palavras para descrever quem faz parte de um franquia. Mas, qual é realmente o termo correto? **"Franquiado"** ou **"Franqueado"**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Franqueado*** e ***franqueador*** estão corretos. São os únicos termos reconhecidos no dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003):

> **franqueado** *adj.* (sXIV cf. FichIVPM) **1** que se franqueou ▪ *adj.s.m.* COM[ÉRCIO] **2** que ou aquele que detém a franquia (‘licença’) ʘ ETIM part[icípio] de *franquear* […]
>
> **franqueador** /ô/ *adj.s.m.* (*sXIX*) **1** que ou o que franqueia **2** COM[ÉRCIO] que ou o que concede franquia (‘licença’) ʘ ETIM rad[ical] do part[icípio] *franqueado* + *or;* ver *franc-*

O dicionário Houaiss, tal como o [Aulete (6)](http://www.aulete.com.br/franquear) e o [Michaelis (5)](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?id=8ne9), traz também a aceção correspondente de *franquear:*

> **franquear** […] **5** *t.d.* COM[ÉRCIO] conceder franquia (‘licença’) a <*a empresa de laticínios franqueou vária lojas na região*>

*Franqueado* e *franqueador* são também os termos usados na lei brasileira, [lei No 8.955, de 15-12-1994](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/l8955.htm), que “[d]ispõe sobre o contrato de franquia empresarial (franchising)”; Portugal não tem lei específica sobre esta matéria.

No fundo a escolha entre *franqueado* e *franquiado* depende se concebes a palavra como particípio de *franquear* ou de *franquiar*. Estes pares de palavras são quase todos homófonos. Mas algumas flexões de [*franquear*](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Conjugar/franquear) e [*franquiar* (Priberam)](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Conjugar/franquiar) são diferentes. Portanto a escolha é entre:

> *os franqueadores **franqueiam** os franqueados* ou *os franquiadores **franquiam** os franquiados*

Ora o Aulete, Michaelis e Houaiss nem têm o verbo *franquiar*. O [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/franquiar), [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/franquiar) e dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (2001) têm, mas apenas com o significado de ‘pôr selo ou franquia em (carta ou encomenda postal)’, o que não justifica *franquiado* e *franquiador* no sentido aqui pretendido. No entanto a [Infopédia tem *franquiado*](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/franquiado), possivelmente porque há gente que escreve assim, mas remete para *franchisado*.

Answer (score 0):

Existem as duas palavras. No entanto, enquanto "franqueado" é o termo habitualmente usado para referir uma franquia, "franquiado", pouco utilizado, é sinónimo de "franchisado" (área da economia).
Fonte: [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/franquiado).

Comment: António, bem-vindo à comunidade. Essa definição de *franquiado* parece ser uma peculiaridade da Infopédia e nem sequer se justifica face às definições deles, ou doutros dicionários, de *franquiar* e *franquear*. Os dicionáros brasileiros que consultei, incluindo o Houaiss, nem têm *franquiar* (apesar de vir na ABL).

Comment: Outro coisa, nós aqui não incluímos saudações ou informação pessoal nas respostas ou perguntas. Esses elementos vão com certeza ser retirados da tua resposta. Mas podes incluir essa informação pessoal no teu perfil.